# Comparison of Brillouin Zone Sampling Methods: K-points vs. Q-points

Tags: vasp, phonons, phonopy, phonon-dispersion

When conducting phonon calculations in VASP using DFPT (Density Functional Perturbation Theory), how do the results obtained using KPOINTS and QPOINTS files compare?

Comment: +1 but please see: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/5

Comment: Aren't they completely two different concept? Afaik, k-points grid is used to sample electronic Brillouin zone (Bloch wavevectors) while q-point grid is used to sample phonon Brillouin zone (phonon wavevectors). [This](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2155/6055) question might help you in terms of choosing q-points

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin while running vasp calculations should we use QPOINTS file instead of KPOINTS along with INCAR,POSCAR and POTCAR?